# Animation over video

Tags: video

I have a video of a guy doing push ups. On that video I want to be able to draw some lines showing what angles the arms should be at when the guy is down and up. The lines should follow the guy on screen as he doing the exercise to show the viewers the correct way of doing the exercise.

Can anyone suggest any software that I will be able to use to achieve this effect? I have looked at Final Cut Pro but it is unclear if I can draw primitives (lines, circles etc.) with this package on screen.

Answer (score 2):

[**Adobe After Effects**](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) is the go to program for motion graphics. There are a lot of resources [available online](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=adobe%20after%20effects%20basics%20tutorials) in the form of tutorials and guides to help you get started. Something like you are describing is a simple enough task, but still requires a basic understanding of AE.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a free application that can do this, it should be do-able in [Wax](http://www.debugmode.com/wax/) without too much effort.

Tracking the arm movements will be a pretty manual process, but the modelling in Wax is good - you also have a lot of other useful effects to make the end result fit well.